# Setting Up Scenerios in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have 2 test plans,
1)Login
2)View Statement
3)Logout

I want to create scenarios, like
1)Login-Logout
2)Login-View Statement.

I have tried using throughput controller, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two thread groups,namely
1) Scenario 1,2
2) Add Login and Logout to Scenario 1. 
3) Add Login and view statement to Scenario 2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best option is using [Module Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-using-module-controller/), this way you will be able to re-use this `Login` part in both scenarios and not to violate the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

1. Add [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) somewhere to your Test Plan and put your Login logic there

   [image]
2. Add [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) where you want perform the login and point it to the Test Fragment from point 1

   [image]
3. Repeat the same for the Login - View Statement scenario

   [image]